# Altium Document/Schematic Option Revision field auto value from Subversion

Tags: altium, subversion

How do I instruct [Altium Designer](http://www.altium.com/altium-designer/overview) to fill `Document Option Revision field` with the value of current [Subversion](https://subversion.apache.org/) revision:
[image: Document Options Window]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the special string `=VersionControl_RevNumber`.

You can find a full list of strings on Altium documentation. The strings are separate for [Shecmatics](http://www.altium.com/documentation/17.0/display/ADES/Sch_Obj-TextString((Text+String))_AD) and [PCB](http://www.altium.com/documentation/17.0/display/ADES/PCB_Obj-String((String))_AD).

Schematic special strings start with a `=` and PCB special strings start with a `.`. When you start typing, Altium will give you suggestions for the available strings, so you can find the right one even if you don't know the full string.

Comment: A bit more explanation on special strings would be good in case the link breaks...

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Thanks, I edited my answer. I did consider copying the list of strings from the docs, but that would make a very long answer that would eventually get out of date.

Comment: Great answer.  I asked similarly,  and was told there was no linkage to SVN.